# Multiple replace for the String in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column present which is as shown below

```
Column1
-------------------------------
{Tablets/Tonic} Benadryl 25 mcg IV
{Tablets/Tonic} Coughx 50 ml IV
{Tablets/Tonic} Nucel 1 mg IV
{Tablets/Tonic} ColdYmx 2 mg IV
etc.,
```

How we can achieve the desired output as two separate columns which is expected (shown below)

```
Column1                  column2 
----------------------   ---------
Benadryl                 25 mcg IV 
Coughx                   50 ml IV
Nucel                    1 mg IV
ColdYmx                  2 mg IV
etc.,
```

Comment: Does the column `Column1` never contain spaces ?

Comment: Your query doesn't actually work as shown.

Comment: @Luuk It has spaces as shown in Column one(Original)

Comment: I'm trying to Remove '{Tablets/Tonic};' 1 column with name 'Benadryl' and 2nd column with values '25 mcg IV'

Comment: What happens if the drug or medicine name itself is two words?

Comment: Sorry, I did mean you final column `Column1`, where you now end up with `Benadryl`. Can that contain a space too ?

Comment: @Luuk Yes, space will not be a problem

Comment: @YenRuby how did you get on?

Answer (score 2):

Just continue what you started a second time and substring the results from the first substring. (`cross apply` is just a fancy way to do a sub-query).

```
declare @MyTable table (Transcript varchar(64));

insert into @MyTable (Transcript)
values
('{Tablets/Tonic} Benadryl 25 mcg IV'),
('{Tablets/Tonic} Coughx 50 ml IV'),
('{Tablets/Tonic} Nucel 1 mg IV'),
('{Tablets/Tonic} ColdYmx 2 mg IV');

select
    substring(ActualName, 0, charindex(' ',ActualName)) Column1
    , substring(ActualName, charindex(' ',ActualName)+1, len(ActualName)) Column2
from @MyTable
cross apply (
    values (substring(Transcript, charindex(' ',Transcript)+1, len(Transcript)))
) x (ActualName);
```

Returns:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| Benadryl | 25 mcg IV |
| Coughx | 50 ml IV |
| Nucel | 1 mg IV |
| ColdYmx | 2 mg IV |

Note: Your query as shown doesn't actually work - you don't want to start from 15 the start is from the first detected space.

Comment: I'm new here. I already have a table. Any other way to get the desired result instead of declare and cross apply?

Comment: ```
Column2
-------------------------------
{Tablets/Tonic}
{Tablets/Tonic}
{Tablets/Tonic}
{Tablets/Tonic}
etc.,
```

```
Column1
--------------------
Benadryl 25 mcg IV
Coughx 50 ml IV
Nucel 1 mg IV
ColdYmx 2 mg IV
etc.,
```
This is the result I got when I used 

substring(ActualName, 0, charindex(' ',ActualName)) Column1
    , substring(ActualName, charindex(' ',ActualName)+1, len(ActualName)) Column2

Comment: Your data can't be the same as you posted then. You need to update your question with accurate data. Which is exactly why I created a table variable with your data to test, so show that it actually works. Also you could create a dbfiddle.

Comment: I will edit the question. Not sure on DBFiddle

Comment: With https://dbfiddle.uk/ you can copy my solution, add the new data, and show me how its not working.